# How to dynamically add a class to li item and change its background color using javascript and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here I have a list, what I want to do is I need to change the list ( **li** ) background color to different one after click on a specific list item. the thing is once it click on the link page will be redirected and refresh.  please can me suggest a solution for to get this done?

```
<div id="main-menu">  
    <ul id="main-menu-list">      
      <li id="menu-home"><a href="main/home">Home</a></li>    
      <li id="menu-profile"><a href="main/profile">My Profile</a></li>
      <li id="menu-dashboard"><a href="main/db">My Dashboard</a></li>
      <li id="menu-search"><a href="main/search">Search</a></li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

what i did for this :

**Java Script :**

```
var make_button_active = function()
{
  //Get item siblings
  var siblings =($(this).siblings());

  //Remove active class on all buttons
  siblings.each(function (index)
    {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
  )

  //Add the clicked button class
  $(this).addClass('active');
}

//Attach events to menu
$(document).ready(
  function()
  {
    $("#main-menu li").click(make_button_active);
  }  
)
```

**CSS :**

```
#main-menu-list li.active {
  background: #0040FF;
}
```

Comment: Is these LI's in a master page? or do they appear on each page as shown?

Comment: yes. it appears in the each page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little difficult to tell exactly what you want to do, but here's some quick and dirty (and untested) code:

```
/// when we click on an `a` tag inside the `#main-menu-list`...
$('#main-menu-list').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    // stop the link from firing
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    // change the list item's background to green
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('myClassName').css('background-color', 'green');

    // do anything else, e.g. load in pages via ajax...
});
```

You could use CSS to apply the green background color, instead of jQuery:

```
.myClassName { background-color: green; }
```

This will stop the page from navigating, and I don't know if that's your intention. If you want to check the currently-loaded page against the menu to find the current item, you could do this (on page load) instead:

```
var currentPage = window.location.pathname;

$('#main-menu-list').find('a[href^="' + currentPage + '"]').closest('li').addClass('active');
```

***EDIT:***

Your amended Javascript code can be simplified to the following:

```
$('#main-menu li').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    // only do the following if the clicked link isn't already active
    if(!$(this).closest('li').hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).closest('ul').find('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');

        // load in your content via ajax, etc.
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ekW8S/1/)

Comment: I think you got my problem sir, can you recheck the edited code and tell me what should i do. In the above code what i'm doing is creating a class called 'active'  and add css to that active class. Here what i get i once the page reload that created 'active' class get vanished as soon it created. i need to keep that class though the page get refresh. can you suggest me a solution for that?

Comment: Sure; I've edited my response to add a function that should do the trick. Replace your javascript with this (inside the '`$(document).ready` function)...

Comment: I think i'm almost there, but there is a one small issue with that once i click on the specific link it does change its background color, but it does not go to specified url in the <a href=""> tag, and also i notice that when i click on the several list items it does not remove class tag once creating a new one?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I missed `.closest('li')` out of a couple of lines. I've updated my answer and added a link to a JSFiddle where you can see it working. If you want to load the content in, you'll need to extend the function (where it says `// load in your content via ajax, etc.`) to handle it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the JSFiddle thing. You mean i have to get the clicked url and redirect it to that page after that isn`t it? don't be angry about the silly question about that i'm asking i'm very much new to java script and ajax. Basically what is want to do is when click on the list item it need to redirect to the specifies url and the clicked item has to be highlighted. Can you help me bit more? please if you don`t mind

Comment: In that case there's really no need to add the `active` class on click, as you want it to act as a link and the page will refresh. Just use the snippet immediately above the `EDIT:` text and that should do the job.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49477/discussion-between-chamika-kasun-and-massivepenguin)

Answer (score 1):

For each page you can add a class to the current list item that has "where the user is"..

CSS:

```
.selectedItem{
     background-color: orange;//whatever color your want for the selected tab..
 }
```

Then for each of your pages,

say you're in Dashboard.html

your menu code will look like:

```
<div id="main-menu">  
 <ul id="main-menu-list">      
    <li id="menu-home"><a href="main/home">Home</a></li>    
    <li id="menu-profile"><a href="main/profile">My Profile</a></li>
    <li id="menu-dashboard" class="selectedItem"><a href="main/db">My Dashboard</a></li>
   <li id="menu-search"><a href="main/search">Search</a></li> 
 </ul>
</div>
```

in profile.html:

```
<div id="main-menu">  
 <ul id="main-menu-list">      
    <li id="menu-home"><a href="main/home">Home</a></li>    
    <li id="menu-profile" class="selectedItem"><a href="main/profile">My Profile</a></li>
    <li id="menu-dashboard"><a href="main/db">My Dashboard</a></li>
   <li id="menu-search"><a href="main/search">Search</a></li> 
 </ul>
</div>
```

and so on..

Comment: There are no pages dude. theres only a one base .html file and other details will be loaded after clicking on the list item

Comment: I asked him this in comments, 
 
`Is these LI's in a master page? or do they appear on each page as shown? –  JF it 19 mins ago  ` 
   
`yes. it appears in the each page. –  Chamika Kasun 16 mins ago`

So I assume he means ul appears on each page..

Comment: also in question `link page will be redirected and refresh. `
so there is more than 1 page. @ChamikaKasun Otherwise It doesnt make much sense lol

Comment: Sorry i thought its like that. please be sorry about the misunderstand

Comment: No problem - MassivePenguin's answer is perfect for you then.. :) I'll leave this here unless people are confused about the comments/etc

Comment: <3 no problem , this is why its important to give as much information as possible :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the background color when the document is loaded (i.e. in document.ready).

Then you need a mechanism to connect the currently loaded page to one of your list items.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //get the url from the current location or in some other way that suits your solution
    //perhaps use window.location.pathname
    var moduleId = "dashboard" // hardcoded to dashboard to make the point :);

    $("#menu-"+moduleId).css("background-color", "#ccc");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9JaVn/1/